# REST best practices: should a store also return metadata?

Tags: api, rest

I'm building my first REST API (at least trying) for a personal project.

In this project there are resources called `player`s which hold can be in a `team`. According to [REST API design rulebook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do) a resource should be made either to be a *document* **or** a *store* and one should keeps these roles as segregated as possible.

Yet I would like to append some metadata to the `team` resource, eg the date the `team` was founded. Is it okay then for `GET /teams/atlanta` to return this metadata (making it a *document*) alongside the list of `player`s in the team (making it a *store*).

Is this a good idea? If so why? If not why not and how to solve this better?

I know there are no rules to developing a REST API, but there are good practices and I would like to adhere to those. Please also not that this is really my first REST API so pardon my ignorance if there is any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend having `GET /teams/atlanta` return just the information about the team, such as the founding date that you mention, and then having `GET /teams/atlanta/players` return the list of players for that team. These distinctions become more important when you are presenting an API that uses HTTP methods other than GET.

For example, if you wanted to add a player to a team - this would be a lot easier if you could just POST a player object to `/teams/atlanta/players` than if you had to PUT the whole team object to `/teams/atlanta` every time you wanted to add one individual player.

If your API only allows retrieval of data, and if it is for a specific client application, there is an argument for combining all the team data into one object to save the client having to make additional requests for the data, but bear in mind that it is less flexible.

Your application may want to display a list of teams by calling `GET /teams` but you probably wouldn't want all of the player information included in each object in the list as this is quite a lot of data, but if `GET /teams/atlanta` returns player information then it would be inconsistent not to include it in the list version too.

I would personally favour splitting up the resources as I've suggested, and live with the fact the client may need to make an extra request or two.

Comment: nice didn't think of that! this way teams can also more easily be extended (eg `/teams/atlanta/mascots`). I guess I just don't have the REST mindset yet.